# Access '13 - Does not recognize field name Error, Crosstab to Report Issue

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax-error, crosstab

### The Background

Each month I run a crosstab query which is then "spruced up" with an Access Report.

CROSSTAB SQL:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(myTable.Field1) AS SumOfField1
SELECT myTable.Date, Sum(myTable.Field1) AS [Daily Totals]
FROM myTable
GROUP BY myTable.Date
PIVOT myTable.Field2;
```

where Field1 is a $ Amount, and Field2 (for this example) is either going to be "Option1", "Option2", or "Option3".

TYPICAL CROSSTAB RESULTS:

```
Date     Option1    Option2   Option3
-----    --------   --------  --------
Day1      $5.00      -$2.37   
Day2                  $3.15
Day3                           $2.22
```

### My Issue

Because 99 times out of 100 I'm going to have data in each "option" in a given month I created a report that cleans up the crosstab results in a "pretty" format. This month however, my raw data didn't have any "Option3" values. As a result the crosstab column for Option3 doesn't appear on my query results. Then, since the report pulls directly from the crosstab & looks for each option column by name, this causes my report break giving the error:

> The Microsoft Access database engine does not recognize '[Option3]' as
>   a valid field name or expression.

### Troubleshooting

I've tried a few things with respect to troubleshooting:

1. =Nz(Sum(myTable.Field1),0) in the SQL... however this just yields 0's where NULL for the *existing* values of field2 - thus "Option3" does not appear as a column of all 0's.
2. =Nz([Option3],0) in the report... still get the error above (field not recognized)
3. =IIf(IsError(Option3),0,(Option3)) in the report... get the error:

> The expression you entered contains invalid syntax

4. =IIf(IsEmpty(Option3),0,(Option3)) in report... same as above
5. =IIf(IsMissing(Option3),0,(Option3)) in report... same as above

At this point, I'm at a loss regarding how to get my existing report to run (just displaying a column of 0's for "Option3").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Specify column headings](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html#ColHead) with an `IN` list in the `PIVOT` clause.

```sql
PIVOT myTable.Field2 IN ('Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3');
```

Those column headings will then be included in the query result set (in the listed order) regardless of whether or not the source data includes any rows with those values.

A side effect is if the crosstab data source could ever include an *Option4*, it would not be included in the resulting columns.  That is fine for your report since it wasn't designed to expect an *Option4* column.  But it might be a concern if you're using the crosstab query elsewhere.

In the report, you can use `Nz()` to substitute zero for Nulls from the options columns.

Comment: Has anyone ever told you you're brilliant? Can't believe I didn't think to do that (sometimes I get too wrapped up in Access functionality to think normal SQL)... but this worked like a charm, thank you!

Comment: Never!  :-)  I discovered that feature when I wanted month name crosstab columns to appear in month order instead of alphabetical order.  So it's useful for more than one reason.  Regards.

Comment: Great solution there, HansUp!

Comment: Mine was caused by a complex column that was selecting values using a formula. PIVOT Query doesn't seem to like over-complexity. So now I do that computation in the report.
With regard to whether or not a column(s) will have values, I manage mine in the report with a Try...Catch statement in the code behind (.rdlc) and just skip the code trying to get the data. I have tried several ways, I don't seem to get your error just because a column did not have a value; you may want to check other complex formulae in the columns as well...

Comment: As with the limitation mentioned in the solution, can't that be done with a separate query giving the columns in the desired format? eg SELECT Cols FROM Table. Format them to a string array then supply it to the statement... Just thinking it could work...