# MS Access reporting a blank value if field does not exist

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a query that pulls in various fields from an external crosstab query.

However, in some cases, a particular field may not exist, e.g. `externalCrossTabQuery.someField`.

How can I get my query to default this to a blank / null value if that field doesn't exist?

Comment: Modify `externalCrossTabQuery` so that it always includes `someField` in its output fields.  See [Does not recognize field name Error, Crosstab to Report Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35755161/77335)

Comment: As @HansUp shows, explicitly add such a field in the crosstab's `PIVOT` clause. Crosstabs are dynamic queries that will adjust structure (i.e., columns) depending on data values. You can filter and define columns in pivot clause.

Comment: So something like "Select * from crossTabQuery PIVOT (field1, field2, field3, ..., field k)" ? Or add the pivot to the end of crossTabQuery?